# No reply from GSM module

Tags: arduino-due, gsm

I have an arduino due sending and receiving data from a server using a GSM module (UBLOX SARA-U270). The issue I am having with it is that after a period of time working correctly the module stops replying or replies with random characters. It has been suggested to me that if I receive no reply to a command and continue to send commands it can cause issues like this and I need to take action before I send any more commands but I am unsure of what this action should be.

I was wondering is there a recommended action to be taken if I receive an empty response from an AT command to a GSM module after it has been previously working. I am currently working to find out the cause of the issue but I just wanted to know what should be done if an AT command that replies with nothing.

To try and correct this issue I have a function in place which if the module hasn't received data correctly for 1 minute will clear the modules setting using the AT+CFUN=1,1 command and resend all the setting to the module. My issue is that because the module is not replying, my AT+CFUN=1,1 command does nothing.  Physically removing the power to the module seems to be the only thing that will get it running correctly again.

And suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated, Thanks guys.

Comment: Good question, I'm experiencing similar problems (different GSM module). My initial thoughts were something to do with the baud rate, however, tried various different options and same issue eventually happens. Second thought was then power, I've read on few occassions that if the correct power isn't supplied then it can cause undesirable behaviour.

Comment: Hi James, I think the most important thing, with regards to these modules is to pay close attention to the timeouts for each command. Ensure that you don't send any other commands to the module until you either receive a reply to the last command or have waited the full timeout for the sent command. I rewrote my code paying close attention to this and had much more success.